# Magento Free Shipping for Match Items Only - Using Table Rates Based on Order Total

Tags: magento

Can I achieve the following with Magento:

I'm using a table rate system of price vs destination. And I've got a shopping cart price rule of Free Shipping for products with the attribute free_shipping -> to set yes.

This works fine if you have normal products in the basket OR free shipping products in the basket. However if you have both a normal product AND a free shipping product in the basket. It calculates the shipping based on the order total including the product with free shipping.

How can I correct this, so the shipping is applied only to the order total of products not including free shipping, when both type of products exist in the basket?

Is there a Magento Plugin for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and implemented a small code change to make it work.

Basically forget the promotion rule. Disable it. It doesn't seem to work properly with the shipping rates table when applying free shipping to individual items. The shipping rules seem to take precedence and calculate based on cart total.

The trick is to subtract the free shipping items from the cart total at the point the Shipping Rates module is making the calculation.

In my case everything inside a particular category (id:15) was to get free shippping. But you can amend the logic to suit your needs.

You will need to amend the following file (or copy it to your local codebase to do things properly).

> app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate.php

CHANGE THIS:

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                    $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
                }
            }
        }
```

TO THIS:

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
    //And Exclude items which should have Free Shipping
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {

       $freeshipping_category_id = 15;

        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                    }
                        //If it's in the free shipping, remove it's value from the basket
                        $arr_category_ids = $child->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
                        if ( in_array($freeshipping_category_id, $arr_category_ids) ) {
                            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                        }
                }
            } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
            }
                //If it's in the free shipping category, remove it's value from the basket
                $arr_category_ids = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
                if ( in_array($freeshipping_category_id, $arr_category_ids) ) {
                    $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your sales rule set the Free Shipping to 'FOR MATCHING ITEMS ONLY'.

Comment: I have the following already setup for the shopping cart price rule:

Free Shipping: For Matching Items Only
Stop Further Processing Rules: No




Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    Free Shipping  is  Yes

Comment: Have you enabled your 'Free Shipping' module? You need that too. Enable it and set it to minimum order amount of something massively huge so it does not show up by default.

Comment: Have enabled Free Shipping, and set the minimum order amount to "100000000000000000000". However the issue remains the same unfortunately :( Any other ideas? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: You might want to see if it is your rule setup (smallest detail can throw it out) or the shipping module. Unfortunately I have removed the default shipping modules/modified them so I cannot try before suggesting. You could also try a workaround, a shopping cart rule that discounts from the total, to see if that adds up correctly.

Comment: I'm going to try the workaround, of correcting the shipping with another shipping cart price rule. Unfortunately this means creating 32 price rules at the moment! Thanks for your suggestions :) hopefully someone has an idea of how to correct this, without a time consuming work around.

Comment: Try it on a vanilla install of demo products, you should be able to get this working. The tax might be different for our shipping to goods and whatever sales reports, so do persevere!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, the solution is really easy and quick, here is how I've solved it:

In the file: Validator.php (/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/)
search for the string "case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::FREE_SHIPPING_ITEM:" and just before the "break;" add this simple thing "$item->setWeight(0);"

This will force the weight of the item to be 0 so no shipping price will be calculated on it, and if you disable the free shipping option for hat item, the weight is considered and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I've got the following now:
case Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::FREE_SHIPPING_ITEM:
    $item->setFreeShipping($rule->getDiscountQty() ? $rule->getDiscountQty() : true);
$item->setWeight(0);
break;

But we're using Price vs Destination, not weight - so I think that's why your patch doesn't work for us. Any ideas on what we could use instead in this location?

Comment: Ouch, when i've enough time I can look better into that, unfortunately Price vs Destination will never take account of the weight as you pointed out, my bad, I missed the part about price vs destination. Unfortunately is a nasty bug from magento, hopefully I can write back with some news within tonight.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help :) I'm sure we'll be able to solve this issue.

Comment: Hello mpark, unfotunatley I'm late and without any news, I'm too busy at work to give a solution to that right now x__x

Almost forgot, you should check the file shipping.php as far I could tell from the spare time I had, there the shipping costs are handled an you could see if the free shipping check is truly applied when you are working on more than 1 item.

Comment: Hey man, I don't know if you solved your issue, but I just found something that might help you, http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/enable-free-shipping-promotions-with-magento-table-rate-method/ enjoy!

Comment: Hi Matteo, Thanks for the link! Unfortunately, that fixes Magento versions prior to 1.4.2, I'm running Magento 1.5.1.0 so that code is already patched. Let me know if you find anything else, as the issue is still there :( Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has been answered and accepted, but I would like to offer a way to do this without programming, or changing core files if at all possible

If you want to create your item as a "Virtual" item, you can exclude virtual items from shipping fees

**If item is created already**

Go to your database with a program like phpMyAdmin and navigate to `catalog_product_entity`, find your product SKU and change `type_id` to `virtual`

**If item is not created**

Create item as `Virtual Product` during the first step of product creation (instead of `Simple Product` or `Bundled Product`, etc.)

**To exclude `Virtual Products` from shipping fees**

Navigate to `System > Configuration > Shipping Methods` and under the `Table Rates` header set `Include Virtual Products in Price Calculation` to **No**

- Please note, this will only work for, and is only necessary for, the `Table Rates` shipping method
- UPS, USPS, FedEx and DHL determine by weight, so since Virtual Product types have a product weight of 0 it will not affect shipping costs for these methods